# Start and stop MS Access VBA code on a specific time

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have some MS Access VBA code, and I am using code for IE navigation.

Now I wish to create another event so that I can start the above VBA code after a specific time and then stop the code after a specific time.

Start and stop code is listed below but it is not working properly.

```
Private Sub Command13_Click()
Dim t1
Dim t2
Dim t3
For i = 1 To 10000
i = 1
t1 = Now()
t2 = "2/27/2016 11:55:35 AM"
t3 = DateDiff("n", [t1], [t2])
'run specefic vba code
If t3 < 5 Then
get23
If t3 > 10 Then Exit Sub
'stop specific vba code i.e get23
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Use Form.Timer and .Timerinterval

Comment: see: [TimerInterval Property](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TimerInterval-Property-9732dbbb-3f6f-4eb7-995d-b695f3d9d4b8)

Comment: Is this possible to start and stop vba code after specific time interval?

Comment: Form.timer and timeintrrval works.

Comment: I set Timer_Interval=1200000 and Please VBA Code name in Form_Timer,but code is not running after each 20 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You have to dim properly:

```
Private Sub Command13_Click()

    Dim t1 As Date
    Dim t2 As Date
    Dim t3 As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    t2 = #2/27/2016 11:55:35 AM#

    For i = 1 To 10000
        t1 = Now()
        t3 = DateDiff("n", t1, t2)
        If t3 < 5 Then
            ' Run specific VBA code
            get23
        End If
        If t3 > 10 Then 
            ' Stop specific VBA code i.e. get23
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

That noted, if you call the code at any time not within 5 minutes of t2, it will just loop once and exit or loop 10000 times in a split second.

**Note**

For any variation of your code the issue will be, that your application will lock up while the loop is running. This is why you should study the use of the *Timer* property of a form as already mentioned which - though still can cause some troubles - will leave the application responsive.

Comment: Thanks...If i want to stop macro after each 30 minutes and then want to run after each 35 minutes then what will be changes in code?

Comment: Then you should follow the link to TimerInterval as mentioned above.

Comment: Try this: [Timer demo](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9A761BDD515E1B67!54688&authkey=!AMLCvEcJYYh4kXI&ithint=file%2cmdb)

Comment: When i click on above link..following message appears...Sorry, something went wrong
Our server is having a problem. We're working to fix it as soon as we can, so try again in a few minutes.